# Change bootstrap4 button "search" text

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

When I click to "Search" button on my site http://junjob.ru/
I go to http://junjob.ru/search/?q=&q2=ALL

**How can I change text "search" to "my_search" in this link?**
I need http://junjob.ru/my_search/?q=&q2=ALL

I am using django web-framework. And fix should support queries from form

**My code**

**vacancy_list.html**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px; font-size: 2rem; padding-left: 0px;">
        <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="q2" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                         <option>Other</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">

                     <button  class="btn btn-primary">Search</button> <!-- BUTTON -->
                 </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**views.py**

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancy_list/vacancy_list.html'
    paginate_by = 5
    page_kwarg = 'vacancy'
    context_object_name = 'vacancies'
    queryset = Vacancy.objects.order_by('-published_date')

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
        """Paginate the queryset, if needed."""
        paginator = self.get_paginator(
            queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
            allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
        page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg
        page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1
        try:
            page_number = int(page)
        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            else:
                raise Http404(_('Page is not “last”, nor can it be converted to an int.'))
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
        except InvalidPage as e:
            raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
                'page_number': page_number,
                'message': str(e)
            })


def vacancy_detail(request, pk):
    vacancy = get_object_or_404(Vacancy, pk=pk)
    print("ZZZZZZ: {};{};VACANCY;{};\n".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), request.user, pk))
    log_to_file("{};{};VACANCY;{};\n".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), request.user, pk))
    return render(request, 'vacancy_list/vacancy_detail.html', {'vacancy': vacancy})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='vacancy_list'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('vacancy/<int:pk>/', views.vacancy_detail, name='vacancy_detail'),
    path('company/<int:pk>', views.company_detail, name='company_detail'),
    path('vacancy/<int:pk>/request', contact_us, name='contact_us'),
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the url, simply edit your `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my_search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    ...
```

keep in mind that as you are using **nameed** urls, instead of hard coding them, you don't need to change your html templates.

Answer (score 3):

you should change your slug;

```
urlpatterns = [
path('my_search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

next this you have to do makemigrations and migrate

Answer (score 1):

```
path('my_search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results')
```